# Re-run the same macro until last row of data

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm a beginner. Just learning by Googleing, but cannot find a solution for this. Please help.

I want to run the below macro. 
I have multiple cells named "CV_=CVCAL" in the same column. 
What I want is for the macro to find the first cell with the value "CV_=CVCAL" and offset to the adjacent cell. If the adjacent cell has a particular value, if the value is below lets say "1.5" i want to fill it will a cell style 'bad'.

I want the macro to go through all the cells that have the name CV_=CVCAL and do the same thing until there is no more cells named CV_=CVCAL.

```
Sub If_CV()

Range("A1").Select

    Set FoundItem = Range("C1:C1000").Find("CV_=CVCAL")
    FoundItem.Offset(columnOffset:=1).Select

    If ActiveCell.Value >= 1.5 Then
    ActiveCell.Style = "Bad"

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I think you can do this with conditional formatting and avoid VBA entirely btw.

Answer (score 0):

A basic loop would be simpler:

```
Sub If_CV()

    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each c in ws.Range("C1:C1000").Cells
            If c.Value = "CV_=CVCAL" Then
                With c.offset(0, 1)
                    If .Value >= 1.5 Then .Style = "Bad"
                End With
            End If
        Next ws
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. That worked perfectly! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. How would you run this to do it on all workbooks?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to loop through your values.

1. Determine the end of your range
2. Loop through your range and check your criteria

---

```
Sub If_CV()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    If ws.Range("C" & i) = "CV_=CVCAL" Then
        If ws.Range("D" & i) >= 1.5 Then
            ws.Range("D" & i) = "Bad"
        End If
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```